# Глітер чи ґлітер?

Tags: іншомовні-слова

Допоможіть визначитися, як передається g  із англ. слова glitter. Мої міркування такі, що маємо загальне правило з правопису, а ще маємо випадки вжитку. Тож, як правильно?

> § 87. G, H
>
> G і h звичайно передаються літерою г

[Правопис](http://www.pravopys.net/#search=86-89)

> **Глітер** - це розсипчасті, дрібно нарубані різнокольорові блискітки, що
>   мають найширший спектр застосування в творчості, макіяжі і манікюрі, в
>   рукоділлі, в поліграфії.

[Стаття](https://100idey.com.ua/uk/glittery-blestki-melkie-krasnye-49879.html)

> Мені хотілося доповнити відштамповану панельку золотом та **ґлітером**. Я
>   взяла фарбу із золотим ґлітером, якою пофарбувала іншу панельку
>   акварельного паперу.

[zgharda](http://stampsblog.zgharda.com/zaproshenyj-dyzajner-ashwini-guest-designer-ashwini/)

> Червоного оленя та цифри я покрила тонким шаром **ґлітеру**.

[Аграфка](https://blog.agrafka.com.ua/novorichni-lystivky/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лїпше робити чіткіше запитаня, а саме — правильно за чим? Позаяк матимемо декількох напрямків, котрі згадаю тут. Також наголошу, шчо далеко не вперше вже подібне питаня ([наприклад](/q/347/)) піднімали ся, себто варто добре пошукати, перед тим як запитувати.

## Діјсна

Себто те, шчо затверџене: основною нормою правописаням мови, як не повторювально чи дивно звучить, є згаданиј чинниј правопис.

Основна ӧго проблема, шчо чинниј правопис занадто слабкиј в роздїлі про запис слів з чужомов, так як правила зроблені за ріжними напрямками, а саме:

- звичаями, хоча переважно сє прикрите «промосковське»
- звучнєво.

Такиј розбіг і дає суперечок, а саме — не всї, приклад тому ваші згадані дописи — хочуть писати за сӥм правописом поза кола затверџеного письма, хоча подекуди і навіть не поза.

## Звучнєво

Тут очевидно, шчо анґліјське *g* — се *ґ*. Також зазначу, шчо подібна розбіжність з *і*—*и*, тобто за правописом *і*, а звучнєво — *и*, котре, про всяк наголошу, далеко не *ы*. Себто звучнєво правильно — *ґлитер*.

## Словопохоџенєве

Одна з причин, чому я таки відповідаю на сӧго питаня.

Слово походить від ІЕ [**ghel-*](//etymonline.com/word/*ghel-), і багато наших слів, як мовить [ЕСУМ](http://izbornyk.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) — *глянець*, *глядіти*… — з того ж коріня слова, і наразі переважно успадкували ся саме через *г*, котре колись було *ґ*, а деякі слова, особливо західноукраӥнського штибу під впливом нїмецької, таки продовжували писати ся через *ґ* — наприклад *ґлянець*. Тому коли треба передати барви частини чи вимову Украӥни, то вибираєте належну букву.